# Settings.jar not found

Tags: android, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

When I am importing phone-Gap project created from CLI in Android Studio, I got an error like:-

```
  **"Cannot find file `" 'C:\my-app\platforms\android\settings.jar' "` .**
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the `Build` file then performing `Clean Project`, then rebuilding your project.

Comment: I try from my side and it's work..
Uninstall previously install application and install again .. it's workable..

Thank you for your support guys..